# Can B be uniquely determined from A and A->B? Similarly, can A be uniquely determined from B and A->B?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can $B$ be uniquely determined from $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$? Here's my attempt using the truth table:

| $A$ | $A\rightarrow B$ | $B$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | T/F |
| F | F | undefined (leads to a contradiction) |

Similarly, can $A$ be uniquely determined from $B$ and $A\rightarrow B$? My attempt using the truth table is provided below:

| $B$ | $A\rightarrow B$ | $A$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T/F |
| T | F | undefined (leads to a contradiction) |
| F | T | F |
| F | F | T |

T/F means the statement can be true or can be false. To elaborate, for instance, if $A$ is false and $A\rightarrow B$ is true, then we can not uniquely determine the truth value of $B$ for $B$ can be true or $B$ can be false.

Comment: What is the conclusion you reached from your attempt?  In particular, note the "T/F" entries in your tables.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question. I believe the answer to both of my questions is 'no'. Can you clarify what else you are asking of me?

Comment: Your conclusion of "we can not uniquely determine (in some circumstances) the truth value of $B$" is the same conclusion I would expect and seems to be the correct answer to your question in the title.

Comment: So it looks like you are answering your own question, Pragnya.

Comment: These are really weird truth-tables ... normally you start with atomic statements, and given their truth-values, you progressily find the truth-values of larger and larger statements involving those atomic statements. But you seem to assign a truth-value to $A \to B$ before assigning one to $B$ ... but then also end up with T/F entries. So I am not sure how you went about creating these 'truth-tables' and how you filled out the columns .. can you please explain?

Comment: In an answer below, your phrase "uniquely determined from $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$" is interpreted as "uniquely determined from the premise that both $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$ are true." This interpretation is likely because often in such contexts we don't write "$P$ is true," we just write $P$. But I think you meant to ask if the truth value of $B$ is uniquely determined whenever you know the truth values of $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: @Bram28 Well I first wrote down the truth table for $A\rightarrow B$ with $A$ and $B$ taking up all possible permutations of truth values. And then I proceeded to work out in reverse the truth table for $B$ using $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$ as input elements.

Comment: @DavidK Yes you are right, indeed. I was referring to whether the truth value of $B$ can be uniquely determined from the truth values of $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: @PragnyaJha When you 'write down the truth-table for $A \to B$ with $A$ and $B$ taking up all possible permutations', you are describing the normal way to do a truth-table ...but that is not at all what you did. A normal truth-table looks like what DanChristensen has in the Answer below. That is, *first* you figure out all possible truth-value combinations for $A$ and $B$, and *then* you work out the truth-value of $A \to B$. So to generate the table, you don;t start with $A \to B$ and $A$, and then work back to $B$ (which is what you seem to do).

Comment: I deleted my answer. The OP has already answered his question.